# Can any version of android be installed on a device

Tags: android

I've recently ran into an error with an Android app I'm developing. It requires me to have a device with an exact version of Android installed. (specifically 4.1.1 or 4.1.2) I've been looking around for the exact answer to my question and so far I have found nothing useful.

Can you install **ANY** stock version of Android on **ANY** android device? Or are their restrictions/compatibility issues that limit your options?

My original plan was to use `fastboot` to flash 4.1.2 factory image onto my Nexus 7 (2013 Edition). However, I discovered that google doesn't provide an image that goes back to 4.1.2 for this device. Does this mean it isn't possible or is there another way to accomplish this (shy of purchasing a device that can).

Comment: **"It requires me to have a device with an exact version of Android installed. (specifically 4.1.1 or 4.1.2)"** : Urrm, WHY? This makes no sense.

Comment: I don't know the answer, and you've probably tried this, but: Any chance you can just reproduce the bug in the emulator running the desired version?

Comment: It actually does make sense. All devices with Adreno GPUs that have Android 4.1.2 are crashing. With the following error: libGLESv2_adreno200.neon_pld_min_max_16, but its very funny that everyone is so focused on the fact that I needed an exact version of android installed.

Comment: Derek Kurth - We are developing the app using Unity3D. In my experience Unity3D apps don't install on an Android simulator, and if they do they crash. Unity3D at this time only ports to ARM platforms. ARM simulation for us has been slow and clunky.

Comment: `an Android app I'm developing. It requires me to have a device with an exact version of Android installed. (specifically 4.1.1 or 4.1.2)` ... such a **poor design**!!

Answer (score 2):

> It requires me to have a device with an exact version of Android installed. (specifically 4.1.1 or 4.1.2)

Why?

Moreover, what is "an exact version of Android"? Samsung's 4.1.2 is different than HTC's 4.1.2, which is different than LG's 4.1.2, which is different than Motorola's 4.1.2, etc. Android is open source; device manufacturers and ROM modders can and do tweak the innards. Whether those differences matter for your situation, I cannot say, because you have not explained what your specific problem is.

> Can you install ANY stock version of Android on ANY android device?

No.

> Or are their restrictions/compatibility issues that limit your options?

Drivers, for one.

> However, I discovered that google doesn't provide an image that goes back to 4.1.2 for this device.

Among other reasons, that device never had 4.1.2 on it. It initially shipped with Android 4.3 (or some patchlevel of 4.3).

Comment: Why? The app is crashing with the following error: (Java.lang.error in libGLESv2_adreno200.neon_pld_min_max_16) on devices that have Adreno GPUs that run Android version 4.1.2. I want to test my fix for this bug in the environment that we see the failure. If there is another way to address the problem please tell me.

Comment: @PeterGrantBue: "I want to test my fix for this bug in the environment that we see the failure" -- clearly, you know the actual devices that are failing, so go buy one on eBay or your other favorite site for purchasing back-level hardware, instead of wasting your time trying to create some Frankendevice that may or may not wind up exhibiting the problem.

Comment: I am with @CommonsWare on this one. Even if you manage to find/build an Android 4.1.2 image for your device, you have zero guarantee you will reproduce the bug, as the issue might be in how the driver on that device is configured. The only reliable way to test (aside from shipping in production :-)) is to get the exact same device and test on it.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: **No.**

Longer answer: Android OS consists of several different "layers" (or "facets" is a better word?). These include, but are not limited to...

- Linux kernel, under GPL
- Android Open Source Project, under Apache/MIT
- Hardware drivers, mix of open source and proprietary
- Proprietary Google apps (Google Play, Gmail, Google Maps, etc.), proprietary

In order for a specific version of Android to be built for a particular device, the OEM has to potentially license specific drivers for some of the hardware components, like for example camera or Bluetooth chip used in the phone. These licenses cost money, and since most OEMs operate on very thin margins, they don't bother to license these for distribution in any other form than as part of a whole system package. This precludes the OEM from offering a download version of these apps and drivers so you could build your own version of the Android Open Source Project for their devices.

At the same time, a big part of releasing a device is going through Google's certification process (part of the Google license). This is time, effort, and money costly process, so OEMs try to minimize the number of system images they produce that need to go through it. This typically is done only for the version of Android the device is shipping with, and maybe one or two versions after that, if the device is incredibly successful, and there are millions of it sold, and the OEM feels generously and is willing to update the OS. Most OEMs couldn't care less though.

In addition, the device also has to go through carrier certification, which is yet another time, effort, and money consuming process. This is an additional incentive for the OEM to not care about producing additional system images, since Google and carriers are the only ones that really continue to monetize the user, and anything done past the device sale is a sunk cost for the OEM.

Specifics: In particular, the issue with the Nexus 7 is that Google has never produced 4.1 system images for it. And in general, Google has never produced backported images for any of their development devices.

Comment: That is what I assumed, but I wanted someone that knew more about the inner working of the Android OS to confirm it. Thank for your detailed response to my question.